# Should MySQL columns always have Default Values?

Tags: mysql, ddl

Is it best practice to always have default values on MySQL columns?
Does this improve performance?
I have set my columns to be `NOT NULL` but have not specified a default value.
Is this bad practice?

Answer (score 6):

> Is it best practice to always have default values on mysql columns?

NO

It really depends.
If you want to ensure that sensible data is input, then you should **not** set a default value for a `not null` column.
Only set default values for columns that have a sensible default value.
If you can get away with `null` just allow `null`.

> Does this improve performance?

It slows down your inserts *ever so slightly*.
But may it speed up your selects, because you don't have to test for null.
Of course the DB spends a small amount of time to setting the default values.
Unless you're inserting in bulk it's very unlikely you'll notice any delay.

Answer (score 3):

**Performance**

1. **Inserts** Theoretically, it *should be faster* to use default values instead of sending every all values. In fact the performance difference is so small, you can not measure it.
2. **In general**: Using **NOT NULL is faster** than working with NULL values. Specially index structures work faster if they do not have to handle the Null values.
3. If you use NOT NULL **use Default**  value

**Best Practice**

In real world you should do, what you desire to have as an outcome.

- Use NULL values if you want to keep the information "I don't know the real value"
- Use DEFAULT value, if you don't care if you know the real value, but you want to make sure that at least a default value is present.
- If you use NOT NULL always use DEFAULT.

**Examples**

- Birthday: **Do use NULL** values for those users, you don't know the birthday.
- isDisabled: **Do not use NULL**, instead set default to 0; so if there is nothing set, the User is not disabled. You decide, so you don't need NULL.

Answer (score 1):

If your specifying it as NOT NULL then yes you should have a default value unless your controlling what data is inputted.  NOT NULL implies there will always be a value so having a default value is good practice.  Do all of your columns need to be NOT NULL?

Comment: This is not universally applicable. It's just not true to say that it's always good for a column to either be nullable or have a default value. For example, a primary key field would be NOT NULL but you certainly wouldn't set a default value. Nor would you give, say, a username field a default value.

Comment: @Hammerite I agree you don't want to set a default values for those items but in those cases your going to control that there will be a value inputted by validation on the front end.  If your validating your inputs are not null then no you don't need a default value. But if your not doing that validation and have no default value and someone tries input a null value then a SQLException happens and that is poor practice.  Really you shouldn't set all columns to be NOT NULL unless it's truly necessary.

Answer (score 1):

No! The default values ​​are used when you need one, but not setting not impacts in the performance!